# Second highest value

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the code so that I can get the first and second highest value.

I am able to get the first highest value.

However, I am unable to get the second-highest value.

I am using VBA as a tool.

```
Sub abc()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim lr As Integer
    Dim minvalue As Double, maxvalue As Double

    Worksheets("Player_Statistics").Activate

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lr
        pn = Cells(x, 1).Value
        pp = Cells(x, 2).Value
        pa = Cells(x, 7).Value

        If Range("b" & x) = "Allrounder" Then
            Range("g" & x) = (Range("c" & x) * Range("d" & x)) * 10000 / (Range("e" & x) * Range("f" & x))
        ElseIf Range("b" & x) = "Batsman" Then
            Range("g" & x) = Range("c" & x) * Range("d" & x)
        ElseIf Range("b" & x) = "Bowler" Then
            Range("g" & x) = Range("e" & x) * Range("f" & x)
        End If

        If pp = "Allrounder" And pa > maxvalue Then
            Range("a14").Value = pn
            Range("b14").Value = pa
            maxvalue = Range("b14")
        End If
    Next x

    For y = 2 To lr
        If pp = "Allrounder" And pa > minvalue And pa < maxvalue Then
            Range("a15").Value = pn
            Range("b15").Value = pa
        End If
    Next y
End Sub
```

My data:
[image]

I am not getting any error message. However, value is not getting printed either.

Could please do let me know where I am missing something.

Hope for some positive response.

Regards,
Aiyub

Comment: Did you only want to find Highest and Second Highest Numbers within Allrounders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code didn't give me the Highest Number either...

Step through your code again, and you'll see why.

I think you need three different loops to:

- Calculate Scores in Column G
- Get Highest Number
- Get Second Highest Number

This is what has worked for me:

```
Sub abc()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim lr As Integer
    Dim minvalue As Double
    Dim maxvalue As Double
    Dim pn As String
    Dim pp As String
    Dim pa As Double

    Worksheets("Player_Statistics").Activate

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lr
        pn = Cells(x, 1).Value
        pp = Cells(x, 2).Value
        pa = CDbl(Cells(x, 7).Value)

        If Range("b" & x) = "Allrounder" Then
            Range("g" & x) = (Range("c" & x) * Range("d" & x)) * 10000 / (Range("e" & x) * Range("f" & x))
        ElseIf Range("b" & x) = "Batsman" Then
            Range("g" & x) = Range("c" & x) * Range("d" & x)
        ElseIf Range("b" & x) = "Bowler" Then
            Range("g" & x) = Range("e" & x) * Range("f" & x)
        End If
    Next

    For x = 2 To lr
        pn = Cells(x, 1).Value
        pp = Cells(x, 2).Value
        pa = CDbl(Cells(x, 7).Value)
        If pp = "Allrounder" And pa > maxvalue Then
            maxvalue = pa
            Range("a14").Value = pn
            Range("b14").Value = CStr(pa)
        End If
    Next

    For x = 2 To lr
        pn = Cells(x, 1).Value
        pp = Cells(x, 2).Value
        pa = CDbl(Cells(x, 7).Value)
        If pp = "Allrounder" And pa > minvalue And pa < maxvalue Then
            minvalue = pa
            Range("a15").Value = pn
            Range("b15").Value = CStr(pa)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```